# How to read a file from a URI using StreamReader?

Tags: c#

I have a file at a URI that I would like to read using StreamReader. Obviously, this causes a problem since File.OpenText does not support URI paths. The file is a txt file with a bunch of html in it. I have multiple web pages that use this same piece of html, so I have put it in a txt file, and am reading it into the page when the page loads (I can get it to work when I put the file on the file system, but need to put it in a document repository online so that a business user can get to it). I am trying to avoid using an iframe. Is there a way to use StreamReader with URI formats? If not, what other options are there using C# to read in the txt file of html? If this is not optimal, can someone suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are behind a proxy don't forget to set your credentials:

```
  WebRequest request=WebRequest.Create(url);
  request.Timeout=30*60*1000;
  request.UseDefaultCredentials=true;
  request.Proxy.Credentials=request.Credentials;
  WebResponse response=(WebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  using (Stream s=response.GetResponseStream())
    ...
```

Answer (score 17):

Is there a specific requirement to use `StreamReader`? Unless there is, you can use the `WebClient` class:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
string readHtml = webClient.DownloadString("your_file_path_url");
```

Answer (score 13):

You could try using the `HttpWebRequestClass`, or `WebClient`. Here's the slightly complicated web request example. It's advantage over WebClient is it gives you more control over how the request is made:

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(lcUrl);

httpRequest.Timeout = 10000;     // 10 secs
httpRequest.UserAgent = "Code Sample Web Client";

HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());

string content = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
```