# Why i get URI formats are not supported in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm new in c#,and write this code:

```
const string file ="http://ipaddress/"+"1.jpg";
                                        var fileName = file.Split('\\').Last();
                                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                                        {
                                            var fts = new FileToSend(fileName, fileStream);
                                            await Bot.SendPhotoAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, fts, "Nice Picture");
                                        }
```

but in this line:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
```

get this error:

```
URI formats are not supported
```

How can i solve that problem ?thanks.

Comment: See the answers for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460503/how-to-read-a-file-from-a-uri-using-streamreader

Comment: Why split on "/" when there aren't any in your source string?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use WebClient instead of `FileStream` for this. Here's a link that might help you: [URL Formats are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918433/url-formats-are-not-supported)

Hope it helps!